# How to add as key one value, as value something else?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to display months, but in key to add number of month and for value to add name month. I have this code but problem is that when i foreach that and dispay $key it always give me name. Any suggestion how can i fix this?

```
 $archive = [];
  $archive_current_year = Articles::where('approved',1)->whereBetween('created_at', [
      Carbon::now()->startOfYear(),
      Carbon::now()->endOfYear(),
    ])->get()->groupBy(function($item) {
        $archive[Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item->created_at)->month] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item->created_at)->formatLocalized('%B');

    return  $archive;
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't group by an array. You need to return a string from the callback.

If you want to group by month then it would be:

```
$archive = Articles::where('approved',1)->whereBetween('created_at', [
    Carbon::now()->startOfYear(),
    Carbon::now()->endOfYear(),
])->get();

$archive_by_month->groupBy(function($item) {
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item->created_at)->month;
 });
```

Also, you don't need to create `Carbon` instances in the `groupBy`, by default in Laravel `created_at` and `updated_at` are already `Carbon` instances.

```
 return $item->created_at->month;
```

Should work just fine.